# NotNullViolation when appending to relationship using an Association Object in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**Background**

[The documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) gives the following example of a parent-child-association being added by appending that association to `p.children`. The child is then accessed via `p.children` and I assume the other way is possible as well, i.e accessing the parent via `c.parents`.

```
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(50))
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Association", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parents = relationship("Association", back_populates="child")
```

```
# create parent, append a child via association
p = Parent()
a = Association(extra_data="some data")
a.child = Child()
p.children.append(a)

# iterate through child objects via association, including association
# attributes
for assoc in p.children:
    print(assoc.extra_data)
    print(assoc.child)
```

**Problem**

I have three classes that are almost identical to those in the example:

```
class TopicSubcription(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'topic_subscription'
    topic_id = Column(ForeignKey('topic.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    subscription_date = Column('subscription_date', DateTime, nullable=True)
    topic = relationship("Topic", back_populates="subscribed_users")
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="followed_topics")

class Topic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   subscribed_users = relationship("Association", back_populates="topic")

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    followed_topics = relationship("Association", back_populates="user")
```

but when I run the following I get a NotNullViolation error stating that user_id violates not-null constaint.

```
    u: User = session.query(User).filter(User.id == 'example_id1').one()
    t: Topic = session.query(Topic).filter(Topic.id == 'example_id2').one()
    sub = TopicSubscription(func.now())
    sub.topic = t
    u.followed_topics.append(sub)
    session.add(u)
    session.commit()
```

**Question**
Am I misinterpreting the documentation or is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had something quite similar just now and was going crazy trying to work it out. Abstracting to the parent/child example from the docs, what worked in my case was:

```
p = Parent()
a = Association(parent=p, extra_data="some data")
a.child = Child()
p.children.append(a)
```